# TYPO3 hack - Viagra and other stuff

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have actual the latest TYPO3 6.2 version ... 6.2.31 ... I know ... working on upgrade.

But now I have a google hack which replaces Links in Google with Viagra stuff. Had this several weeks ago thought I fixed it with update from 6.2.9 to 6.2.31

There is unkown code in Core .. Does any Body knows this and can help me fix the hole?

last time it was here:

```
/data/www/domain/public/typo3/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php
```

Thanks at all

Comment: I thought there are includes of php files in typo3conf/extTables.php or typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the [TYPO3 Security Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SecurityGuide/HackedSite/Index.html) which means that if your website is hacked you must take it offline, check the site, find the security issue and then bring it only.

If your website is hacked, not only your server and data is at risk but every user who visits your website. Especially if users trust you and your knowledge, you should take that issue serious.

Most of the time I have seen this issue one of the following problems occurred:

- Hacked FTP account
- Security issues in custom or 3rd party extensions.

Comment: are there any automatisms to contiuous check for hacks like this?

Comment: there is something like https://github.com/jweiland-net/checkmysite but first a hacker can just disable any code as he is already on the system and 2nd not everything can be found with such things, therefore I would never trust such stuff.

Comment: trust not but it could probably help

Comment: Its every time in this file: `/public/typo3_src-6.2.31/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php` is there a known bug with this file?

Comment: No, there is no bug in this file. The hacker does have a shell on your system, a trojan horse. That means he can do all he wants, he has the same rights as you. He rules the system and is able to change every file he wants to. Normaly they change the index.php or index_ts.php, simply because it is the easies way. Repairing this file get you nothing: You have to find the rat hole where he came in, and than you have to find and delete all trojan horses he has left. Normaly 2 oder more, i have heard about up to five on different places.

Comment: Also note: after you removed all backdoors, make sure you change the backend Password for each and every TYPO3 backend user (at least admin users are most important).